# system Time is showing but with the difference of 1 hour

Tags: java, javafx-2

time is not showing perfectly, I am trying to show my system timings.

Also I am not able to set these

```
int minut = calendar.getTime().getMinutes();
int hours = calendar.getTime().getHours();
int sec = calendar.getTime().getSeconds();
```

It gave error:

```
The method getSeconds() from the type Date is depreciated.
The method getHours() from the type Date is depreciated.  
The method getMinutes() from the type Date is depreciated.
```

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

int hours = cal.getTime();
int minut = cal.getTime();

hours = hours * 30 + minut / 2;
minut = minut * 6;

int sec = cal.getTime();

minut = minut +sec/10;

sec = sec * 6;

hr.setRotate(hours);

minute.setRotate(minut);

second.setRotate(sec);

Scene sc = new Scene(pane);
ps.setScene(sc);
```

It give me the time for example if my system time is 10:25 it shows 09:25

Comment: *"The method getSeconds() from the type Date is depreciated."* Is not an error, it is a warning. Btw: can you please post your real code? Or tell us which `Calendar` you're using?

Comment: Yes its a warning sorry for that.
I used these imports.
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
 
and the whole code I posted already of the calendar. also I want to set time for the region of Pakistan

Comment: If you used `java.util.Calendar`, then your code doesn't compile.

Comment: So what can I do? because if I remove java.util.Calendar so my compler didn't allow me to write this
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

Comment: What you can do? Show us the code you've used to get the time, which was one hour of.

Comment: To get the system time I only used the above posted code and nothing is used to get the current system time.

Comment: So you used the above code with `java.util.calendar` and `int hours = cal.getTime();` works for you, even when `getTime` returns a `java.util.Date` instead of an `int`?

Comment: Yes Its works for me. as you said.

Comment: Could you be in a GMT+1 timezone such as the UK which will mean there is an hour difference between GMT and your local time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes not much sense to me but get keep in mind that Calender.getTimeInMillis() or Date.getTime() return the time in UTC - regardless the timezone you set on the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, it will give you correct time:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ":" + millis);
```

Comment: now only 10 to 15 mint difference is show using this code. Any idea to get exact minutes? as hour is shown perfectly.
Thanks

Comment: Now its my clock stuck at 11:10 ... :(

Comment: I checked its differ from the application/or the code you provided